Makefile and windows `set /p`
I'm writing a makefile for windows and I'm trying to convert his UNIX snippet to windows:
 @read -p "Version? (provide the next x.y.z semver) : " TAG
 @git commit -m "release: version $${TAG} "

My makefile runs as ONESHELL snippet and the unix-variant works flawlessly. However, for Windows i can't find a way to ask the user for an input and use this input afterwards, e.g. with set /p.
 @set /p TAG="Version? (provide the next x.y.z semver) : "
 @git commit -m "release: version %TAG% "

I want to use the native windows powershell/cmd, not something like cygwin.
The problem is, that the environment variable is not set yet since it runs in an ONESHELL (I assume). Additionally, I also can't set any other (temporarly) environment variables to be used by snippets afterwards in Windows.
I tried to enable delayedexpansion (setlocal delayedexpansion), which should be a solution to this problem AFAIK; but this seems not possible inside an makefile.
Using the - Operator to enforce an subshell execution does not work either, as well as putting snippets in an seperated shell with $(shell ...)

SET /P is a Windows cmd.exe syntax. To what value are you setting SHELL = ? And, what part of this question is related to PowerShell?

Hi, I'm using PowerShell to execute everything. SHELL is not set, so the default behavior (https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html); i assume (with no unix-like shell on path).
I'm just looking for a way to get the same behavior as in unix in windows (with no unix-like shell present)

What is the output of make --version?

The Output is GNU Make 3.81

What about
set /p tag="which version?"
echo "will use %tag%"


This will not work, since ONESHELL is activated and in windows you can't refer to a tag without delayed expansion which is defined in the same call. And activating delayed expansion did not work for me

I do not have a Windows computer handy, so I cannot test which of these actually works.  For a batch script, one thing to try is, to put double percent signs into the script; they should be parsed into regular percent signs at execution time.
However, there is a possibility that this also would need delayed command expansion.  As you said, it is not available inside the makefile.  One way to get around it is to use a for statement -- something like this:
for %%a in (`set /p a=Which version? `) do echo Will use version %%a.

